# Add arguments based on the value of another argument

Tags: python

Based on one of the inputs, I would like to initialize certain objects. The values from these objects will be the default values for rest of the arguments. So i need the value of one of the argument even before parser.parse_args(). How can i achieve this with python argparse module. All the options will be given as one command line.

The default values should be shown with help. These values come from object.

```
def cli():
    option1 = None
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--option1', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    #option1 = value from --option1
    abc(option1)
    parser.add_argument('--option2', default=abc.getValue())
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You could parse all of the possible arguments, defaulting to `None` for the optional ones, then updating the values as you need to. There is really no harm in initialising a few variables that you then throw away.

Comment: All of your command-line arguments are initially stored in the `sys.argv` list regardless of the option processing module you use. You can scan that list for the argument you want, to get its value.

Comment: Default values for the option should be shown in the help for the user. The default values changes based on the object initialization. I am editing the actual question too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most efficient, but you can parse the *known* options after defining option 1, then add option 2 to the parser and reparse.

```
def cli():
    option1 = None
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--option1', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()

    abc(args.option1)
    parser.add_argument('--option2', default=abc.getValue())
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

In general, this approach requires that you avoid (or at least be aware of the consequences) option handlers which have side effects, since they will be triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

**It's worth it to sacrifice having unneeded options for the sake of readability/logic.**

If you try to take things out of `sys.argv` before the option parser is done (which would give you what you're asking for) someone who looks at it will think: *"Why did he do that? That doesn't make sense."*

I suggest doing it this way (Based on @Geekfish 's comment):

```
import argparse

def get_option2(option1, option2):
    if option2 is not None: # The user specified an option
        return option2
    else: # The user did not specify an option
        option2 = abc(option1).getValue() # set option2 based on option1
        return option2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--option1', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--option2', default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()

option2 = get_option2(args['option1'], args['option2'])
```

Comment: Sorry that i did not include this initially in the question. I want to show the default values in the help. So i cannot make them None and assign value to them later. I am using this in the parser. formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter

Comment: Ah. heh, I'm not quite sure then. I'm sure it's in the documentation.