# Use an ArgumentParser argument as a default value of another argument

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to set an `ArgumentParser` argument value as the default value of another argument in the same parser.

Desired behavior:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormater)

parser.add_argument('-p', '--pin_file_path', help = "the directory of the given pin file", default=os.getcwd())
parser.add_argument('-o', '--other', help="", default=**pin_file_path!**)
```

Comment: Make it optional, and then manually check and set the value if needed in the parsed args afterward?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700253/add-arguments-based-on-the-value-of-another-argument) help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`parse_known_args` parse the argument and send it to another argument.

```
pin_file_path= None
parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormater)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pin_file_path', help = "the directory of the given pin file", default = os.getcwd())
args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
parser.add_argument('--option2', default=args.pin_file_path)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: yes that how I resolved my pb, thank you so much!